# QWifiManager class include issue

Tags: c++, qt, windows

I want to use `QWifiManager` class, when including it doesn't work?

**The error is:** no such file or directory.

How to use it? Thanks.

Comment: This is part of the "Qt for Device Creation" (commercial I believe) package. Do you have that?

Comment: @Mat

So this class is only exists in paid Qt versions?

Comment: @Cobra91151 Yes : http://doc.qt.io/QtForDeviceCreation/

Comment: @IAmInPLS

I can't find any documentation for Qt 5.9.2. I think it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So seems it only available in paid `Qt` versions and also it maybe deprecated. No new info is available. Anyway, thanks to all.